# How to select date from date fileds using watin framework

Tags: c#, testing, c#-4.0, watin

Can any one tell me how to select a date in these date fields automatically by using [WatiN](http://watin.org/)

(http://www.meanfreepath.com/javascript_calendar/livedemo.html) I have given this site as an example.

I have tried to select a random date as

```
foreach (SelectList sl in lists)
{
    OptionCollection oc = sl.Options;
    temp = random.Next(oc.Count);
    oc[temp].Select();
}
```

It doesn't work as date fields are not selection lists first of all date fields are not selection lists

Is there any other way to solve this puzzle by clicking on the date field an selecting a random value from it?

Comment: @HiTechMagic:  Watin is a web application testing framework.  http://watin.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple options: You can use the `Filter` method or do a for loop through all the tablecells.  I'll be using `Filter` below as it takes fewer lines of code.

Looking through the code for the Calendar, you should see it is a basic HTML table and that the cells are well defined by CSS classes.

**Goal of the example**

Pick a random day in the current month

**Pseudocode**

- Go to the page
- Figure out the number of days in the current month
- Generate a random number base on the number of days in the month
- Pick the day by filtering on the CSS class and the expected text being the random number

**Actual Code**

```
Settings.HighLightElement = false;   //If you don't do this, the calendar colors won't work correctly.
ie = new IE(true);

ie.GoTo("http://www.epoch-calendar.com/javascript_calendar/livedemo.html");
ie.Table("bas_cal_calendar").WaitUntilExists(5);

int totalDaysInMonth = ie.Table("bas_cal_calendar").TableCells.Filter(Find.ByClass(new Regex(@"wkday|wkend|wkday\scurdate"))).Count;

Random random = new Random();
int randomDay = random.Next(1,totalDaysInMonth + 1);

ie.Table("bas_cal_calendar").TableCell(Find.ByClass(new Regex(@"wkday|wkend|wkday\scurdate")) && Find.ByText(randomDay.ToString())).Click();
```

*Note*: I'm guessing the CSS class when the current date is a weekend day would be *wkend curdate*.  This would need to be verified and RegExs updated as needed.
*Note*: After you click on a day, the CSS class changes to *cell_selected*.

The above is tested and good using WatiN 2.1 and IE8